# Pygame music file size limitation?

Tags: pygame, wav

I am able to play wav-files in pygame that are up to 2 mb, but not much larger. Is there some limitation to allowed size? Or what might the reason be? I can play any small files I try. But none larger than 4 mb.

Ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: not that I'm aware of - maybe try to convert them to ogg and see if that problem is reproduceable.. It might be a buffer-size issue - but that's just a wild guess

Comment: Converting to ogg worked fine. Thank you!

Comment: Great - then I will post this as an answer - can you accept it ? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any file-limitation  - maybe try to convert them to ogg and see if that problem is reproduceable..

It might be a buffer-size issue - but that's just a wild guess